# Pokemon Asleep Status

Tags: pokemon

I have looked all over for this and can't find any good information on the sleep status, even in the rule book.

This came up because in a game recently with a friend: I was put to sleep with an attack that had 100% chance to do so, after I had less cards in my deck, effectively causing me to lose.

As I currently understand it, flipping to remove the sleep status happens after my turn, so even if I remove it they can just apply it right away again.

Is this the correct way that sleep works? If so, how do I avoid automatically losing as soon as an opponent has a sleep attack?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [rules](http://www.pokemon-organizedplay.eu/pdf/TCG-rulebook-en.pdf), p15:

> **Between turns**, flip a coin. If you flip heads, the Pokémon wakes up.

So you flip a coin to wake up your pokemon after *every* turn - **both yours and your opponent's**. This means that even if the opponent can put your active pokemon to sleep every turn and you have no other way of cancelling it (like evolving the pokemon, or sending it to the Bench with a [Switch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:SwitchBaseSet95.jpg)), there's still a half chance that by the time your turn starts it'll be awake and able to act.

Comment: ok so i think i was doing this wrong before. the game out be friend puts me to sleep it's my turn and i do my stuff. Then it's their turn again and now I flip to get my pokemon out of sleep condition?

Comment: Yeah, "retreat" is a special action you can take once per turn for free (see p12) but it's blocked by Asleep; "Switch" is a specific card that happens to cause an effect very similar to retreating, and it's not blocked by Asleep.

Comment: aa so to defend against sleep I need to build my deck better it would seem

Answer (score 2):

From the [rules](http://www.pokemon-organizedplay.eu/pdf/TCG-rulebook-en.pdf), p15:

> **Between turns**, flip a coin. If you flip heads, the Pokémon wakes up.

Between turns means, *before **and** after your turn*.  So your opponent does an attack that leaves you asleep, their turn is over, before you do anything flip a coin to see if you wake up *between* his turn and your turn.  if you perform an attack that puts **your** Pokemon asleep your turn is over, but you need to flip a coin to see if your Pokemon wakes up.

If your Pokemon is asleep during your turn, then you can use an item card that removes special conditions or use a [Switch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:SwitchBaseSet95.jpg) to change the active Pokemon, the one that goes to the bench has all conditions removed unless there is a card in play that prevents the loss of the special conditions when a Pokemon is moved to the bench.

Snorlax GX has an attack that can only be used if Snorlax is asleep, I believe there are other Pokemon that operate this same way as well. So you want to be asleep, but you still have to flip a coin after your turn where you put your Pokemon to sleep and before your turn where you use the attack that your Pokemon must be asleep for.